# How do I setup my cpanel site backup on a local host?

Tags: migration, localhost, local-installation, development-strategy

I have downloaded all the files on my server as a `.zip` file via the cpanel interface. I have also downloaded local's [WordPress hoster](https://localwp.com/).

I would like to setup my wordpress site on this local hoster, but when I copy and paste the wordpress files into the local host folder location the website fails. What could be causing this?

Comment: You'll have to ask Local's support team about this. Hosting questions are [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Is this not a question about development? I'm really asking how do I setup a site locally. Seems that's on topic.

Comment: You're asking how to configure and use Local's WP hosting system, which is a third-party product.

Comment: Are migration questions off-topic?

Comment: No, but Local is a proprietary platform owned by FlyWheel/WPEngine and it works in it's very own and specific way.
Set-up an empty instance in Local and then install your plugins and themes as you normally would, then import the DB, but you'll first need to update your DB export so that the WP prefix matches.  Local's support channels and community may have better details about importing the DB.  You can't just drag and drop WordPress into a Local directory, you have to run an instance through the app first and then you can add in you plugins and themes.

Comment: @TonyDjukic Thank you, I got it working!